# manipulating css element with jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I'm still learning jquery.

I want to make a code, if I click on button, 2 divs will move simultaneously and the background will be overlayed by another div with `opacity` of 0.5

[image]

so when I click on menu button, the menu Right and menu Left will move left and right respectively

then `z-index` and `opacity` of `div class="overlay"` will be changed, then check if `#circleMenu` has `.open` class, if not then add `.open` class and move `#left` and `#right` div

I use custom defined function to run it `onclick="show()"`

the code does not work, when I check for problem and error on the console it says :

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token. Uncaught ReferenceError: show is not defined

**EDIT**

thanks to @Tirthraj Barot, the error is now gone.

still my question remains, I expect the code to do this when I click on button :

1. change the overlay background opacity and z-index so it will be overlaying the body
2. move the 2 divs inside circle simultaneously

I expected it to be executed at the same time, but in reality it is not. the first time I clicked on button, only the background is overlayed, the second time, the background overlay is gone but the divs moves

```js
      function show() {
    $(".overlay").css("z-index", 1);
    $(".overlay").css("opacity", 1);
      if ($("#circleMenu").hasClass("open") == true) {
       $("#circleMenu").removeClass("open");
       $("#left").css("left", "-100px");
       $("#right").css("right", "-100px");
    } else if ($("#circleMenu").hasClass("open") == false) {
       $("#circleMenu").addClass("open");
       $("#left").css("left", "100px");
       $("#right").css("right", "100px");
    }
}
$(".show").on("click", function() {
   show();
 });
```

```css
body {
 margin : 0;
 padding : 0;
 width : 100%;
 height : 100%;
}
.overlay {
 width : 100%;
 height : 100%;
 background-color : gray;
 opacity : 0;
 z-index : -1;
 position : absolute;
 transition : all 1s;
}
.kontainer-menu {
 width : 50%;
 height : 30%;
 margin : auto;
 position : relative;
 z-index : 2;
 top : 40%;
}
#circleMenu {
 width : 200px;
 height : 200px;
 border-radius : 50%;
 background-color : red;
 z-index : 3;
 position : relative;
 left : 35%;
}
#left {
 width : auto;
 position : absolute;
 background-color : green;
 top : 90px;
 left : 100px;
}
#right {
 width : auto;
 position : absolute;
 background-color : teal;
 top : 90px;
 right : 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="kontainer-menu">
<button onclick="show()">Menu</button>
 <div id="circleMenu">
  <div id="left"> menu Left</div>
  <div id="right"> menu Right</div>
 </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.overlay should be in double quotes

```
function show() {
    $(".overlay").css("z-index", 1);
    $(".overlay").css("opacity", 1);
    if ($("#circleMenu").hasClass("open") == true) {
        $("#circleMenu").removeClass("open");
        $("#left").css("left", "-100px");
        $("#right").css("right", "-100px");
    } else if ($("#circleMenu").hasClass("open") == false) {
        $("#circleMenu").addClass("open");
        $("#left").css("left", "100px");
        $("#right").css("right", "100px");
    }
}
```

----------------UPDATE----------

I updated the code above.
You forgot to write `px` after 100 and -100 in if and else blocks.

------------ UPDATE 2 ------------

Just to show the simultaneous movement of both the divs, the `left` and the `right`, And to change the background overlay color according to my perceptions,  I have updated your code a little. Please let me know if I have misinterpreted your requirements..

Have a look at it.

```js
function show() {
  if ($("#circleMenu").hasClass("open") == true) {
    $(".overlay").css("z-index", 1);
    $(".overlay").css("opacity", 1);

    $("#circleMenu").removeClass("open");
    $("#left").css("left", "-100px");
    $("#right").css("right", "-100px");
  } else if ($("#circleMenu").hasClass("open") == false) {
    $(".overlay").css("z-index", 0);
    $(".overlay").css("opacity", 0);


    $("#circleMenu").addClass("open");
    $("#left").css("left", "100px");
    $("#right").css("right", "100px");
  }
}
$(".show").on("click", function() {
  show();
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.overlay {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1s;
}
.kontainer-menu {
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 40%;
}
#circleMenu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 3;
  position: relative;
  left: 35%;
}
#left {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: green;
  top: 90px;
  left: 100px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
#right {
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: teal;
  top: 90px;
  right: 100px;
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="kontainer-menu">
  <button onclick="show()">Menu</button>
  <div id="circleMenu">
    <div id="left">menu Left</div>
    <div id="right">menu Right</div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you it works now.  but another question, when I clicked on button once, it just show the overlay, then I click on the button again, now the divs are moving. why can't it be executed at the same time?

Comment: Alright.. Let me have a look.. I ll execute it and will be back in a while. @Citra45Abadi

Comment: I already tried your code, it still not changing the overlay and moving div at the same time

Comment: I tested it.. Divs are moving simultaneously in my browser.. what browser do you use @Citra45Abadi

Comment: And if you are trying the opacity thing, its value is between 0 and 1. so if you make the opacity 1 once, then it remains 1 untill you yourself make it 0 @Citra45Abadi

Comment: I am using chrome browser...  as for the opacity, yes I figured that and changed my code

Comment: thank you this is better than I expected. so you changed the overlay first then add/remove the class... hmm

Answer (score 1):

Change your button to:

```
<button class="show">Menu</button>
```

Then in your jQuery use:

```
$(".show").on("click", function() {
  show();
});
```

Sets an on click handler for the button element. See: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: hi thank you for that. I did what you suggest, but the first click still just changes the overlay, and the second click moves the divs